# Removing section separation line just if on top of page

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, sections-paragraphs

I have horizontal lines separating my subsections and I would like to remove them only if they are on top of the page. Anybody can help me? Thanks!

Here is the code snippet of the header of the subsection.

```
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
{\titlerule[.4pt]\vspace{-2ex}\hspace{-\LeftMargin}\normalfont\sffamily\large\bfseries}
{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{2em}{0pt}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\leaders`; in this way, the line will not appear at the top of a new page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
{\leaders\vrule width \textwidth\vskip0.4pt\normalfont\sffamily\large\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{2em}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section one}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Test subsection two}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Test subsection three}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Test subsection four}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Test subsection five}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Test subsection six}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I slightly changed the original settings, since they produced a rule overlapping the heading text, but you can make the required adjustments according to your needs.